# Move a local commit to un-master local branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

I am in complicated situation, because Im not familiar with git;

I had a master commit in remote, I have made a branch from it in my local called `fix-bug-online-offline-support`.
During my work, another team member changed the remote master and I pulled it.

But I need to split my branch `fix-bug-online-offline-support` to two branches;

- One with name : `fix-bug-online-support`
- another with name : `fix-bug-offline-support`

I have changed name of branch `fix-bug-online-offline-support` to `fix-bug-online-offline-support`

and need to move some of commits from `fix-bug-online-support` to `fix-bug-offline-support`

Note: Both of those branches are local branch, and I have hash string of commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: you can use `cherry-pick` to take a commit and put it into `fix-bug-offline-support` and `rebase -i` to then remove commit from the original branch.

**Long answer**: as far as I understand, you have something like this

```
A - B - C - D - E
                L fix-bug-offline-support
```

and you want to end up with something like this

```
A - C' - E'
 \       L fix-bug-offline-support
  \
    - B' - D'
           L fix-bug-online-support
```

you can do:

```
git checkout A # replace A with the sha1 of this commit for instance
git checkout -b fix-bug-online-support
git cherry-pick B
git cherry-pick D
```

At this point we have

```
A - B - C - D - E
 \              L fix-bug-offline-support
  \
    - B' - D'
           L fix-bug-online-support
```

so we still need to remove those commits from `fix-bug-offline-support`, which we do with

```
git checkout fix-bug-offline-support
git rebase -i A
```

and from the text editor that would appear after the `rebase -i` command, delete the lines which correspond to `B` and `D`

**Last subtlety**: Note that we're not actually "moving" commits. We're rather creating new commits. It may sounds like a pedantic nuance, but actually Git can be very hard to understand when we don't pay enough attention to such nuances. So, to clarify:

- A commit is a snapshot of our project and is immutable (eg: it has a sha1 which is unique and that will never change)
- When we `cherry-pick`, we're actually re-applying the patch elsewhere, and git ends up creating a new commit with a new sha1 (eg: that's why in the graph above the commit `B` is turned into a commit `B'`: they're not the same object)
- Same thing when we delete a commit: actually git will re-apply the history without those patches, hence it will end up creating new commits `C'` and `E'`

and a practical corollary is that the initial commit `E` still exist at the end of our manipulations. We don't care because we don't need it and anyway it's not accessible from a branch anymore so it won't block us. But it's a good news because if we notice that we messed up, we can still retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

First try merging origin master into your local branch fix-bug-online-offline-support (kind of reverse merge). Your local branch is now up to date with origin master. Now you can continue your work in this branch.
You can also split your local branch into two branch online-offline.

Comment: Ok, How can I split my local branch, to two branches?

Comment: Checkout your local branch(offline-online) and create two new branch 1.Offline 2. Online. Then after you are done first merge these two branch into your local and finally your offline-online into master and then push.